# datagridview data pass into crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

this is my code for my crystal report:

```
private void MonthlyReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();
        DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter table = new DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
        DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable tables = table.GetData();
        report.SetDataSource(tables.DefaultView);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();


    }
```

and this is my code for datagridview when im filtering data that i want to print.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string searchValue = textBox1.Text;

 dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataTable1BindingSource.Filter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'","bill_desc", searchValue    );
 //here you can do selection if you need
```

}

my problem is how will i pass the filtered data to the crystal report that is in different form. please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a .Net dataset as the datasource for a Crystal Report:

```
  report.SetDataSource(DataSet1);
```

You can either filter the dataset instead of the datatable view or you can create a temporary dataset that only contains the filtered data and set it as the data source.

Comment: You would replace the report.SetDataSource(tables.DefaultView) call. This would allow you to work directly with the data before passing it in. Likewise you could just pass the searchvalue into the crystal report as a parameter and then filter the record selection based on that value.

Comment: when i replaced the code i always get an error or a red line under in DataSet1

Comment: the error i got is ('DataSet1' is a 'type' but is used like 'variable')

Comment: You'll need to pass in an instance of DataSet1. Do you already new up an instance of DataSet1 in your code?

Comment: im sorry but i dont know how to pass an instance. this is my first time in c# so i dont know how.

Comment: Whoops, It'd look like this:

DataSet1 data = new DataSet1();
report.SetDataSource(data);

This generates a 'instance' of the Dataset that can be modified, added to, deleted from, etc.

Comment: i already put the code but why is that there is no data showed in crystal report?

Comment: This is getting hard to explain via comments. There is a MSDN article here that explains the basics : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301570.aspx and a code example here: http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2006/09/14/91197.aspx . Note that you need to fill() the dataset with data in order to get data into the report.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();
            DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter table = new DataSet1TableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter();
            DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable tables = table.GetData();
            report.SetDataSource(tables.DefaultView);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;

           // crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();//Remove this line
```

Try this hope it's work.